# JS, selecting a div's child

Tags: javascript

If I have

```
function OnMouseIn (elem) {
            elem.style.display= "block";
        }


<div onmouseover="OnMouseIn (this.XXXXXXX)">
    <div class="classname" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

What do I have to write in place of XXXXXXX to select the div's child "classname"? 
(note: there are a lot of the first div, and i have to select only the one where the mouse just got over.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Should look like:  <div class="classname" style="display:none"></div>

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't do this with CSS? Like `.hoverblock:hover > div.classname {display:block;}`?

Comment: Do you want the first child with that particular class or the first child element in general?

Comment: Diodeus: corrected.
Zeta: to write faster.
Felix: I have a lot of div with "onmouseover", and each of them has only one classname div. I'm trying to show only the classname div child of that div.

Comment: oh wait: zeta, you are telling me I can have a onmouseover effect also with css?

Comment: @user1722791: Yes, that's what he is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do this, just use CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .classname {
       display: none;
    }

    #parent:hover > div.classname {
       display: block;
    }
</style>

<div id="parent">
    <div class="classname"></div>
</div>
```

but in javascript it would be:

```
function OnMouseIn (elem) {
    elem.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].style.display = "block";
}
function OnMouseOut (elem) {
    elem.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].style.display = "none";
}


<div onmouseover="OnMouseIn (this);" onmouseout="OnMouseOut (this);">
    <div class="classname" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just found out I don't need js, so i'm using css. Thanks.

Comment: A really nice discovery ;) You can do almost everything with CSS (even adding text to elements), especially with CSS3. Google a bit to see some amazing stuff :)

Comment: I'm trying to work this out, but it doesn't change anything.
(http://pastebin.com/d4LYyLJh)

Comment: Your code is nice but IF you don't put ANYTHING between GAME and GAMEMENU divs, how can you hover over it ?? It is not drawed... it's time for a new discovery: jsFiddle.net -> http://jsfiddle.net/qvnKd/

Comment: Uhm... actually there is something inside the first <div> (i forgot to draw [...] on the second place... I'm anyway verifying the hypothesis.

Comment: WTF I forgot to refresh. It was always working D: thanks anyway